# ASP.Net Validating GridView controls using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that I have load in edit mode.  The user can then update a row and click the update button for that row to update it.  I need to add validation to each textbox that makes that textbox a required field when they click on the update button.  It needs to be JavaScript because I need to load an alert dialog when the user leaves one of the textboxes blank.  Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?  I'm adding my GridView code below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataKeyNames="intExaminerID,sintDOLDistrictOfficeID">
        <Columns>            
            <asp:TemplateField>                
                <ItemTemplate>                 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("intExaminerID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOID"  Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sintDOLDistrictOfficeID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">                
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharFirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharLastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharEmailAddress") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Extension">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharPhoneExtension") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SSN Block">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSSNStart" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharSSNBlockStart") %>' Width="5em"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSSNEnd" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharSSNBlockEnd") %>' Width="5em"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action(s)">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" OnClientClick="javascript:return Validategrid();" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />                    
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working on the JavaScript aspect of your query but let's get your gridview set up to validate for required fields first:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataKeyNames="intExaminerID,sintDOLDistrictOfficeID">
    <Columns>            
        <asp:TemplateField>                
            <ItemTemplate>                 
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" ValidationGroup="GridView1" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("intExaminerID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOID"  Visible="false" ValidationGroup="GridView1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sintDOLDistrictOfficeID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">                
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" ValidationGroup="GridView1" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharFirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" ValidationGroup="GridView1" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharLastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="GridView1" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharEmailAddress") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Extension">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" ValidationGroup="GridView1" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharPhoneExtension") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SSN Block">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSSNStart" ValidationGroup="GridView1" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharSSNBlockStart") %>' Width="5em"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSSNEnd" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharSSNBlockEnd") %>' Width="5em"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action(s)">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" ValidationGroup='GridView1' CausesValidation='true' runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" OnClientClick="javascript:return Validategrid();" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />                    
                <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

What I've done here is added

```
ValidationGroup='GridView1'
```

to each of your textbox fields, and to your Update button

```
ValidationGroup='GridView1' CausesValidation='true'
```

The ValidationGroups will help trigger the validation on clicking the Update button.

I'll update my response once I work out the JavaScript.